# iOS SwiftUi: NavigationView inside a ZStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

I'm building a custom modifier in SwiftUI.
One of the tasks of this modifier is to wrap the entire content inside a ZStack.
But if I apply this modifier to a NavigationView I have a blank screen.

Should I do something particular to enable the NavigationView inside a ZStack?

### Example Code:

```
struct CustomModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            ZStack {
                content
                Text("Hello")
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
         Text("Greatings")
         .navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
        }
        .modifier(CustomModifier())
   }

}
```

Comment: You didn't provide the code you tried (with navigation)

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini added the code, but as you can see is very basic

Comment: With Xcode 11.2 (11B52) your code works well. Which one do you use? Any more details?

Comment: @Asperi Do you you even see the navigation title?

Comment: Yes, large navigation bar title, Hello, and Greatings. At least in Preview and in Simulator. I've just copy-pasted your snapshot and ran - all just works.

Comment: fixed by updating Xcode from 11.1 to 11.2

Answer (score 0):

it should be inside a NavigationView....

Comment: Well, I'm making a custom modifier that should work with all kind of views, not just with some

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by updating Xcode from 11.1 to 11.2.